# Score not incremented in Android quiz app

Tags: android, sqlite, android-sqlite

I am making a quiz app and while doing this my score does not increment 
even when the answer is correct.  When I compare `currentQ.getANSWER().equals(answer.getText())` and after this `score ++` at that time score is not incremented. The following is my code:

```
 butNext.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            RadioGroup grp=(RadioGroup)findViewById(R.id.radioGroup1);

           answer=(RadioButton)findViewById(grp.getCheckedRadioButtonId());

            if(currentQ.getANSWER().equals(answer.getText()))
            {
                score ++ ;

                Log.d("tag"," " +score);
            }



            if(qid < 5) {

                currentQ = quesList.get(qid);



            }

            setQuestionView();




        }
    });
```

In the next button click, I want to save previous response and increment the score but this is not happening.

DBhelper

```
 private void addQuestions()
{
    Question q1=new Question("Which company is the largest manufacturer" +
            " of network equipment?","HP", "IBM", "CISCO", "C");
    this.addQuestion(q1);
    Question q2=new Question("Which of the following is NOT " +
            "an operating system?", "SuSe", "BIOS", "DOS", "B");
    this.addQuestion(q2);
    Question q3=new Question("Which of the following is the fastest" +
            " writable memory?","RAM", "FLASH","Register","C");
    this.addQuestion(q3);
    Question q4=new Question("Which of the following device" +
            " regulates internet traffic?",    "Router", "Bridge", "Hub","A");
    this.addQuestion(q4);
    Question q5=new Question("Which of the following is NOT an" +
            " interpreted language?","Ruby","Python","BASIC","C");
    this.addQuestion(q5);
}
```

This is my dbhelper where I add all questions and answers.
What should i do? Any suggestion is welcome.

Comment: Log both values.

Comment: i set break point to  answer it will get radio button id but it not comparing with getANSWER() and score is 0 always

Comment: As @CL. said and add `toString()` to your `getText()`.

Comment: Maybe the getAnswer() and answer.getText() are returning 2 differents values. For instance, one contains caps or space. Try to make something like  if(currentQ.getANSWER().trim().toUpperCase().equals(answer.getText().toString().trim().toUpperCase()))

Comment: @zed not working even after tostring()

Comment: @Jameltheone not working

Comment: @kunal nikam before the "if" could you make a log of both the getAnswer() and the answer.getText() and copy it here so we could help